# terraform 13 to 14 unsupported attribute aws_provider

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

To be precise, I have a terraform 12 configuration for instances that I updated to 13, and I'm now trying to update to 14.

Between tf 12 and 13 I had no big issues the required provider poped-up but I knew that one.

But in tf 14, I have a new error:

```
Error: Invalid resource instance data in state

  on ../../modules/ec2-instance/instance.tf line 1:
   1: resource "aws_instance" "default" {

Instance module.logstash_1.aws_instance.default[0] data could not be decoded
from the state: unsupported attribute "network_interface_id".
```

So from what I can see in the last version of the provider it should still work but I have the error. That point of configuration isn't even added in my configuration. The parameter was added by terraform and it's now broken.

Comment: This error seems more likely to be caused by changing the AWS provider version than by changing the Terraform version. Have you also upgraded or downgraded the AWS provider at the same time? If so, it would be helpful to edit your question to mention which version you were using before and which version you are using now.

Comment: I found the issue, It was the required_povider that upgraded the provider version...

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue.

When you go from tf13 to tf14 the required_provider field is added to terraform and the provider version is applied there.

If the field is non existant, it will be added automatically by terraform with the latest provider version.

In my case as I had planned and tried to apply the conf I had to init -upgrade terraform in terraform 14 after added the required_provider field in tf:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 2.0"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 0.12.7, <= 0.15"
  backend "s3" {}
}
```

That allowed me to go back on the old provider and resolve the issue.